# Verify a nonce in Form submission

Tags: nonce

I am new in using Nonce.I am using Nonce like below in a Form

```
wp_nonce_field('add_new_addres','add_new_address');
```

I am trying to verify Nonce like below

```
    if(isset( $_REQUEST['action'] ) && ('newAddress' === $_REQUEST['action']) && (wp_verify_nonce($_REQUEST['add_new_address'], 'add_new_addres'))) {
    
         //more code here
    
    }else {
         //more code here
         
    }
```

`else` block is executing but I need to execute `if` block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is, you are submitting data as POST data, but verifying nonce from GET data.

Here is how you can create a nonce field in a form easily:

```
wp_nonce_field( 'add_new_addres' );
```

Actually, I personally don't use more than 1 parameter when calling the `wp_nonce_field` function.

Then when verify use the following code:

```
if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['_wpnonce'], 'add_new_addres' ) ) {
    wp_die( 'Are you cheating?' );
    // Anything that you want to display for unauthorized action
} 

// Good to go for next step
```

Comment: Thanks You vai @Shah Alom.

Comment: Cheers Brother!